# SQL query and troubleshooting

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Good day to you all, I have a question regarding my sql query on rearranging the data.
the query result look like this.

```
Area | Name | Amount |   Date
  1  |  N1  |   10   | 6/15/2019
  2  |  N1  |   20   | 6/15/2019
  3  |  N1  |   30   | 6/15/2019
  4  |  N1  |   77   | 6/15/2019
  1  |  N2  |   30   | 6/15/2019
  2  |  N2  |   45   | 6/15/2019
  3  |  N2  |   60   | 6/15/2019
```

Is It possible to make the query result into something like this and how do you achieve it?

```
Area | Name | Amount | Name | Amount
  1  |  N1  |   10   |  N2  |   30
  2  |  N1  |   20   |  N2  |   45
  3  |  N1  |   30   |  N2  |   60
  4  |  N1  |   77   | Null |  Null
```

The problem is the user doesn't know the names because it is generated
depending on the date it is inserted.

Comment: if Gordon Linoff post an answer then it is definitely the best solution for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then conditional aggregation would work:

```
select area,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then name end) as name1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then amount end) as amount1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then name end) as name2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then amount end) as amount2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by area order by name) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by area;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how do you make the query to look like this in some cases where you do not know how many Names is generated on a specific date...for example on date 1 there 2 Names but on date 2 you have 3...how do you make the query to automatically change the result and is it possible?

Comment: @Niron11 . . . SQL queries return a fixed set of columns.  You would need to define a maximum (for a static query) or use dynamic SQL.